# VS Community 2022 cannot install dotnet-ef when i try to publish

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core

When I clicked on publish in VS 2022, it gives a dialog to choose specifications of my release when I click on show all settings the EF migrations gives this error.

> Entity Framework Migrations
> X dotnet tool install dotnet-ef
> The tool package could not be restored. Tool 'dotnet-ef' failed to install. This failure may have been caused by:
>
> - You are attempting to install a preview release and did not use the --version option to specify the versi
> - A package by this name was found, but it was not a .NET tool.
> - The required NuGet feed cannot be accessed, perhaps because of an Internet connection problem.

[dotnet ef issue image](https://github.com/dotnet/EntityFramework.Docs/assets/20419743/9ec12b37-fbde-4dc9-8f79-ae2b30552457)

I'm trying to publish an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC applications (target is .NET 6).

I tried the cli to publish `dotnet publish -p:PublishProfile=FolderProfile` give me this error code `MSB4236`, I found the file that is not found located in `C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.419\Sdks` however when I execute that command seems it can't find that location and it says that it couldn't find the file in `C:\ProgramFiles\dotnet\sdk\6.0.419`, so i manually copied the content of `Skds` to its parent directory `..\sdk\6.0.419` then I rerun the command again as result it throws this error `MSB4044 The "ProcessFrameworkReferences" task was not given a value for the required parameter "RuntimeGraphPath".`
then I tried the VS 2022 wizard to publish it gives the error:

> Entity Framework Migrations
> dotnet tool restore
> Package "dotnet-ef" failed to restore, due to Microsoft. DotNet. ToolPackage. ToolPackageException: The tool package could not be restored. at Microsoft. DotNet. Tools. Tool.Install. ProjectRestorer. Restore (FilePath project, PackageLocation packageLocation, String verbosity) at Microsoft.DotNet. Tool Package. Tool Packageinstaller.Install Package To External Managed Location (PackageLocation packageLocation, Packageld packageld, VersionRar at Microsoft.DotNet. Tools. Tool. Restore. Tool RestoreCommand.Install Packages (ToolManifest Package package, Nullable`1 configFile) Restore failed

[dotnet ef issue 2 image](https://github.com/dotnet/EntityFramework.Docs/assets/20419743/94cfee6a-b7ad-41db-9440-c69531310372)

I tried to install it manually using cli:

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef
dotnet tool install --local dotnet-ef
```

It says `dotnet-ef is already installed` but when I tried the same command in other pc it says `dotnet-ef is installed or updated` no matter how many times I ran the command.

I forget to mention that I did not find the .NET Sdk in Visual Studio installer individual components

this is an image from an other pc that has the .NET SDK:

[dotnet ef issue 3 image](https://github.com/dotnet/EntityFramework.Docs/assets/20419743/92d04ec4-04fa-4abb-ae45-4cf285a36895)

and I tried these answers:
[cannot install dotnet-ef tool on windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58764322/cannot-install-dotnet-ef-tool-on-windows-10), also this answer [install dotnet-ef tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71583816/install-dotnet-ef-tool) I did not find `.Net Sdk` as mentioned above.

I did not tried this answer yet [67272316](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67272316/dotnet-tool-install-global-dotnet-ef) because I'm away from the pc that has the issue (Monday I'll try it).

> [my gh issue](https://github.com/dotnet/EntityFramework.Docs/issues/4698).